# Can i make a absolutelayout into scrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I am using a absolutelayout and i need scrollview in that layout.
How can i add scrollview in that.
If can please provide me a example.
Or can i change to any other layout similar to absolutelayout to enable scrollview.
Please share.

Comment: absolute layout is not a recomended one as its depricated and u can replace it with some other layouts like linear or relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use FrameLayout. to set coordinates use margins of inner elements

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout`. It works perfectly with ScrollView.